# How to collect stream of Telegram messages

Tags: telegram, telethon

Is there any library or tools to get streams of Telegram messages? By stream I mean listen to chats, groups, and channel of the client and collect any **new** messages. Something like Twitter Streaming API. I study the Telethon library and I could collect historical data of chats, groups, and channels but I couldn't find any method to listen and get new incoming messages in that library!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telethon does allow you to do that. you need to use `events`. there are various types of events and for your case, you would need to use the NewMessage event.you can read more about that in this link [here](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/basic/working-with-updates.html). here is a snippet that would do exactly what you want that is taken from the link.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

client = TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if 'hello' in event.raw_text:
        await event.reply('hi!')

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```